# $facebook->getUser() return 0

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

Here's my code:

```
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
require_once $path.'/facebook/src/facebook.php';

$e = UserDataBaseManager::getConnection();

$facebook = new Facebook( array (
  'appId'  => 'myId',
  'secret' => 'secret',
   'cookie' => true,
  'domain'=>'mydomain.com',
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();

var_dump($user); //0

if ( $user ) {
  try {
    $me = $facebook->api('/me');
  } 
  catch ( FacebookApiException $e ) {
    error_log( $e );
    $user = null;
  }
}
else {
  echo 'No FB Session.';
}
```

But $facebook->getUser(); allways returns 0.

I downloaded the latest version of Facebook php SDK; but still return 0; 
Why?

Comment: And how is it supposed to guess who you are? Start with example shipped with php sdk, it shows how to *authenticate* user

Comment: You did fill out your application id and secret right? (ensure you don't reveal them publicly mind you)

Comment: You have the code in local or server ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you logged in to facebook while testing this, cause it seems like you're getting 0 because no user are logged in.

```
if ($user){
//If success

}else{

// If not succedeed put link for login page.

}
```